# Positioning buttons in Android

Tags: android, button

I have 5 buttons, each different in width because some have more text than others.

I want them aligned but the problem is that they don't fit in width if the screen is small (on tablet looks perfect but on mobile it doesn't look good at all)

How can I achieve something like in the image below? If the screen size is too small the buttons that don't fit to go automatically on a new line, but if the screen size is big enough to have them all in line.

[image: buttons]

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/id_moduls" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnbmwx6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="BMW X6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnbmwz4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnbmwx6"
        android:text="BMW Z4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnbmw1s3d"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="BMW 1s 3-Doors" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnbmw6sgrancoupe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="BMW 6s Gran Coupe" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnbmw5stouring"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="BMW 5s Touring" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you given every button a width with wrap_content? and put them in a horizontal LinearLayout?
Show us some code, that will make it easier to check the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Android layout engine, your best bet is to set the LinearLayout's `weightSum` attribute to 5, and set each child button's `weight` to 1 and `layout_width` to "0px". If you want something a little more flexible for multiple screens, I wrote a layout engine for Android that can be used to greatly improve how you handle different views for different screen sizes. The library is called AbLE, and you can download it [here](http://phil-brown.github.io/AbLE/).

To use it, create a file in your app's directory called `libs`, and download the file `able.jar` into the `libs` folder. Next, the easiest implementation has you set your `Activity` to inherit from (`extend`) `AbLEActivity`. Next, create a new class called `Buttons.java` with the following code:

```
@Layout
public class Buttons
{

    public static CharSequence text = "button 1";

    @Layout(viewClass="android.widget.Button")
    public static class Btn1
    {
        public static void onLayoutComplete(AbLEActivity context, View v) 
        {
            int[] size = new int[2];
            AbLEUtil.getScreenSize(context, size);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = size[0]/5;
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }

    @Layout(viewClass="android.widget.Button")
    public static class Btn2
    {
        public static CharSequence text = "button 2";

        public static void onLayoutComplete(AbLEActivity context, View v) 
        {
            int[] size = new int[2];
            AbLEUtil.getScreenSize(context, size);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = size[0]/5;
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
            v.setX(size[0]*1/5);
        }
    }

    @Layout(viewClass="android.widget.Button")
    public static class Btn3
    {
        public static CharSequence text = "button 3";

        public static void onLayoutComplete(AbLEActivity context, View v) 
        {
            int[] size = new int[2];
            AbLEUtil.getScreenSize(context, size);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = size[0]/5;
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
            v.setX(size[0]*2/5);
        }
    }

    @Layout(viewClass="android.widget.Button")
    public static class Btn4
    {
        public static CharSequence text = "button 4";

        public static void onLayoutComplete(AbLEActivity context, View v) 
        {
            int[] size = new int[2];
            AbLEUtil.getScreenSize(context, size);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = size[0]/5;
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
            v.setX(size[0]*3/5);
        }
    }

    @Layout(viewClass="android.widget.Button")
    public static class Btn5
    {
        public static CharSequence text = "button 5";

        public static void onLayoutComplete(AbLEActivity context, View v) 
        {
            int[] size = new int[2];
            AbLEUtil.getScreenSize(context, size);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = size[0]/5;
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
            v.setX(size[0]*4/5);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, add this *meta-data* as a child to your `<Activity>` (i.e. below the intent filter):

```
<meta-data android:name="layout" android:value="com.yourpackage.android.Buttons" />
```

where you replace `com.yourpackage.android` with the package name for where the above `Buttons` class is saved.

Now remove the line `setContentView(...)` in your Activity, and run the application. You should now have a white view with the buttons lined up as expected.  If you have more to your layout in an XML file, you can easily add this to your layout by adding this line to the end of `Buttons.java`:

```
@XMLLayout(resourceID="main")//call this whatever your layout file is (removing the R.layout. part)
public static class InnerXML{}
```